# Is it possible to add text in front of a numbered list in word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I made a list as shown in the image. I want to type the month names before the numbers. So Month name will come first, then the numbering, and the remaining text.

eg: April       1.Capsicum           Drawing and colouring

I am not planning to retype the entire list again because it is very large. Can I type in front of the numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

However, you should be able to

- select your paragraphs
- use insert->table->convert text to table to convert each paragraph
  into a cell in a 1-column table
- insert a column to the left
- type your month names in column 1
- remove any table borders

Comment: Please explain the step 2 of your answer.

Comment: When you have selected the paragraphs, you can go to the Insert Tab, Tables group, and click the Table icon. You should see a menu that contains the option "Convert Text to Table". Click that. In the Dialog box that appears, everything should be filled out correctly, but you should ensure that the Number of Columns is 1, and that "Paragraphs" is selected under "seperate text at" (because if you used tabs to separate your columns, "Tabs" might be selected instead. When you click OK, you should then get a table with one column and one row for each paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The best and easy way is to copy the data onto the excel and to move the cell data from right to left.

This should be the best way. Use Excel.

Comment: How can I copy each word from word to each cell in Excel?

Comment: @TominJacob, Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V

Comment: I tried. Words are coming in different cells.

Comment: Please ping me the link of the work file after uploading it into the cloud (If its not private)

Comment: Its private, that why I posted only a part of it as screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a textbox in front then just make the outline, and set the textbox's background to invisible.